# querypath working on local but not server

Tags: php, development-environment, querypath

so I've been developing something using querypath on my local environment which is MAMP based php 5.3.6, but when I moved it to my development server it stops working.  My development server is LAMP based with php 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why it would work on my local but not my test.  I do have the correct php extensions enabled on both environments.

It seems to have something to do with the querypath files in the include. The PHP/MySQL is working fine in both environments. Querypath requires the 'libxml' and 'dom' extensions to be enabled, which they are in both environments. There is nothing showing up in my php error log, if querypath has an error log then that is something I was not aware of.

A basic example is that this will get a response on my local environment:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.google.com';

$html = htmlqp($url);
print '<h1>TEST</h1>';

print_r ($html);

?>
```

On my development enviroment the 'TEST' will not print, indicating that there was some sort of fatal error in accessing querypath.  And, yes, I have checked my relative paths rigorously.

Update: A colleague returned from vacation today, he advised me to try using the qp() function instead of htmlqp(), this did not make anything work better, but it did yield an error, which was helpful: Fatal error: Class '\QueryPath\DOMQuery' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/fGalaxy54/fGalaxy54/include/QueryPath/src/QueryPath.php on line 158

So for some reason the auto loader is not loading the DOMQuery class, and I have been recopying the files to the server to make sure things were not corrupt.  In any case, my colleague pointed me to a copy of querypath he was hosting somewhere else on the server and for some reason that copy works fine.  So, nothing's solved but I have a working copy elsewhere on the server.  Thanks for all the comments.

Edit again for further clarification:

The querypath autoloader was not loading the DOMQuery class, when I used a different autoloader everything worked fine on my development environment.  Not sure if this is some kind of qp bug, but it's a strange quirk indeed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! please read [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). "stops working" is very vague description... what's the error ? can you enable warnings ? log printings ? does PHP even work on your development-server ? does MySQL ? did you try `phpinfo()` and made sure your configured correctly? ...

Comment: @alfasin Thanks for the response.  Yeah, sorry for being vague.  It seems to have something to do with the querypath files in the include.  The PHP/MySQL is working fine in both environments.  Querypath requires the 'libxml' and 'dom' extensions to be enabled, which they are in both environments.  There is nothing showing up in my php error log, if querypath has an error log then that is something I was not aware of.

Correction to my question: my development server is actually on 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10, not 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17.

Comment: Look at the apache error log, you can with "tail /var/log/apache2/error.log" do it after executing your failing code so the error is printed there. then pasted it here.

Comment: Hi @Nelson, I do not get an error when I run that script.

Comment: What happens in the browser?  Just empty space?  In the source code for the rendered output?  Do you get success codes when using debug tools?

Comment: Before the line type "error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');"  then run again, Note the error and then remove those two lines when done.

Comment: Hi @ernie, Nothing happens in the browser or the source, just empty space.  My error logs haven't turned anything up, and I haven't felt the need to use debug tools for PHP in my work yet, can you recommend a good one?

Comment: @robbie I am not getting any errors when I add those lines.

Comment: So, in htmlqp() you have either "exit" or "die" instruction...

Comment: @Robbie the files on my local and development environments are exactly the same.

Comment: I didn't say they weren't. You may have an "if (OnLinux) { die(); }" then it would work on Windows, but fail on Linux. You will get an error somewhere with the error reporting turned on, or you have an explicit die/exit instruction, or you have a function beginning with @ that fails (remove the @ to show those errors).

Comment: which autoloader did you end up using to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hey @aaron-ransley, here is the author info of the autoloader I used: author    Markus Malkusch <markus@malkusch.de>, copyright 2009 - 2010 Markus Malkusch, link      http://php-autoloader.malkusch.de/en/